# Copying header files from a txt file to other csv files using azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am new to azure data factory. I have a list of txt files (created by splitting a huge CSV file - flights.txt). The list of txt files are listed as flightaa, flightab, flightac etc. Only the first file flightaa has the header.
All my files are stored in the Azure blob storage in the input container. I am transforming the file name from flightaa to flight_1.csv with a header for each file. I am using the Azure data factory to copy from the input container to the output along with a header for each file.

How can I store the header from one file and use it as a header for all output files in azure data factory? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract your header from flightaa.txt to a new file as source manually and don't check `First row as header` option.

Then you can get Metadata activity and loop all your file to add header by using Union in Data Flow.

Details:

1.create 4 datasets and two variables as below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
2.get all your txt files by Get Metadata activity.
[image]

3.loop child items with For Each activity and check `Sequential` option.
[image]

4.get array index by using two `Set Variable activity` and pass it to Data Flow.
[image]

[image]

[image]

5.create tow source in Data Flow and union two source. Source1 is `content_file`,Source2 is `headers`.
[image]

6.sink to your output container.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If you just want to store the header in a separate file, just turn "first row as header" off on the dataset, use the file w/header as a source in a data flow, add a Surrogate Key, then Filter where Key=1.

Comment: Wow thank you so much @steve zhao for these detailed steps. !!

Answer (score 0):

Add a Data Flow activity to your pipeline. Inside the data flow, make 1 source for the file with header and 2nd source that uses a wildcard to read the files with no header.

After the 1st source with the header, add a Union transformation to the 2nd source.